# looping through multidimensional array and getting values from property names instead of numbers

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

So I've got a multi-dimensional array, an array containing json object/arrays which contain properties and values. I want to get the property values using property names. I can do so like this with an each loop within an each loop (for looping through both dimensions of the array):

```
jQuery.each( jsonArray, function(i,val) {


 jQuery.each( val, function(j,val_j) {

        if (j == "episodeNumber")  {
        // run some code
        }

});
});
```

But I feel the above code is unecessarily messy. I don't want to use an if statement every time I want to get the value. I want to do something like:

```
 jQuery.each( jsonArray, function(i,val) {

 var test = $(this)[propertyName]; 
  // I've got the value I want now by using the prop name
 });
```

Of course the above code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us how the array looks?

Comment: $(this)[propertyName] doesnt make sense since 'this' is not a dom object here, try this.propertyName instead..

Comment: @ArpitSingh you're spot on. That's what I was doing wrong ... I always get confused when to use $(this) and when to use just 'this' ... so $(this) is only appropriate when the object is already in the DOM?

Comment: Umm maybe.. unless jquery comes up and starts doing something fancy with non DOM objects in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.each( jsonArray, function(i,val) {

 var test = this[propertyName];
  //  'this' is not a dom object here when using named arrays
 });
```